# Как вставить текст во все элементы страницы jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть функция, которая вызывается при клике

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-price" id="btn1" onclick="selectPrice(20000);">Выбрать</button>
```

И заменяет текст в элементе с id="total-price"

```
function selectPrice(summ) {
      $('#total-price').text(summ);
};
```

Но на странице таких элементов с одним id несколько штук.
Как поменять текст во всех элементах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Смысл id (идентификатор) в том, чтобы дать элементу уникальное "имя", по которому можно будет сразу его найти. id не должны повторяться на странице.

• Вместо onclick можно (нужно) сразу в скрипте и прописать клик по кнопке.

• Если цель onclick была в том, чтобы каждой кнопке дать разный price, для этого можно использовать дата-атрибуты

```js
$('.btn-price').on('click', function(){
  var price = $(this).attr('data-price'); 
  // $(this) — элемент, который запустил функцию. Т.е. кликнутая кнопка.
  $('.change-txt').text( price );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-price="20000" class="btn-price">20000</button>
<button data-price="1500" class="btn-price">1500</button>
<button data-price="300" class="btn-price">300</button>

<p class="change-txt"></p>
<p class="change-txt"></p>
<p class="change-txt"></p>
<p class="change-txt"></p>
<p class="change-txt"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(()=>$('p.text').text('замена'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>кнопка</button>
<div id="num">
  <p class="text">просто текст</p>
  <p class="text">просто текст</p>
  <p class="text">просто текст</p>
</div>
```

id должен быть уникален т.е. один на всю страницу, а 100500 штук.

Comment: а если поставить класс?

Comment: Я выложил пример, смотрите.